# How can I store the data in arrow function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, typescript

Here is my arrow function I am storing in this `let s` arrow function,
which I stored inside of a loop and merged all object in `object.assign`. When I run the `let s` arrow function, however, I'm getting a Promise { undefined } error.

```
let s = async() => {
  Object.values(sqlQuery).map(async(o:any) => {
    a.map(async(k:any) => {
      c.map(async(l:any) => {
        var district:any = `select slug from foa_section_content where foa_section_content_id IN (${k})`;
        var [district1]: any = await connection.execute(district);
        var commune:any = `select slug from foa_section_content where foa_section_content_id IN (${l})`;
        var [commune1]: any = await connection.execute(commune);

        s = await (Object.assign(o,{district1},{commune1}))
   
                  })
    })
    
  })
}
    return (s());
```

Comment: Please simplify your code to a [minimal reproducible example]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it easier for us to understand your problem and help you, and you may even find the solution yourself in the process.

Comment: You are assigning to `s` in every call of the innermost callback. Is this intentional? Or are you supposed to be returning the value (since that is what `map` is all about) and then, finally, returning the result of the top-most `map` (the one on `Object.values(sqlQuery)`)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not returning a value from the arrow function. The syntax for an arrow function is:

```
    let s = async() => {
  return Object.values(sqlQuery).map(async(o:any) => {
    a.map(async(k:any) => {
      c.map(async(l:any) => {
        var district:any = `select slug from foa_section_content where foa_section_content_id IN (${k})`;
        var [district1]: any = await connection.execute(district);
        var commune:any = `select slug from foa_section_content where foa_section_content_id IN (${l})`;
        var [commune1]: any = await connection.execute(commune);

        return Object.assign(o,{district1},{commune1});
   
                  })
    })
    
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Varsha Khantwal really thank you i am used in outside this 
let name = await s();
  return (s()); 
for call this let s function but i am getting if console.log(name ) i geeting below error
[
[1]   Promise { undefined },
[1]   Promise { undefined },
[1]   Promise { undefined },
[1]   Promise { undefined },
[1]   Promise { undefined },
[1]   Promise { undefined }
[1] ]

Comment: This occurs because you are not returning anything from the function s(). You need to return a value from the function s() for it to be successfully called.